# Percona: Backup preparation doesn't work ("cannot open ./xtrabackup_logfile")

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, percona-tools, xtrabackup

I've created a MySQL backup with PerconaXtrabackup tool via (thanks to [this guide](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/howtos/recipes_ibkx_stream.html)):

```
innobackupex --user=backupmysqluser --password=xyz --compress --stream=xbstream ./ > /var/backups/db/firstBackup.db
```

It succeeds creating the hot backup. Now I want to test the restoration of it, so then, first, I decompress it:

```
cd /var/backups/db
mkdir decompressed
xbstream -x -C decompressed
```

Now I try to prepare it:

```
innobackupex --apply-log /var/backups/db/decompressed/
```

And the result is this error:

```
160719 20:06:28 innobackupex: Starting the apply-log operation

IMPORTANT: Please check that the apply-log run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful apply-log run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

innobackupex version 2.4.3 based on MySQL server 5.7.11 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 6a46905)
xtrabackup: cd to /var/backups/db/decompressed
xtrabackup: This target seems to be not prepared yet.
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
xtrabackup: Warning: cannot open ./xtrabackup_logfile. will try to find.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
  xtrabackup: Fatal error: cannot find ./xtrabackup_logfile.
xtrabackup: Error: xtrabackup_init_temp_log() failed.
```

It's strange because in the `decompressed` folder there's no xtrabackup_logfile, but there is a file named `xtrabackup_logfile.qp` instead.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not decompressed the Xtrabackup files if they still have the `.qp` extension.

Try using this inside the current folder:

```bash
sudo innobackeupex --decompress --parallel=4
```

where `4` stands for the number of threads you would like to use.

Also, for clean-up afterwards:

```
sudo find ${DEST_DIR}/ -name "*.qp" -delete
```

Comment: Consider [merging your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) -- you seem to have more than one.

Comment: but according to the docs, `xbstream -x` decompresses, which I have already done

Comment: @user1623521 No, `xbstream -x` extracts/unpacks the stream but does not decompress it.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess the word "extract" confused me because it's commonly used in decompression scenarios